# Get Error when i try to redirect the user after register with eventListener (FOSUserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle, event-listener

Curently, i'm working on redirection after register with FOSUserBundle and eventListener,

RegistrationConfirmListener.php

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('bissap_bodyconcept_homepage');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

So, I Get:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to BISSAP\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener::onRegistrationSuccess() must be an instance of BISSAP\UserBundle\EventListener\GetResponseUserEvent, instance of FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent given
```

I try to move

```
 public function onRegistrationSuccess(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
```

by

```
 public function onRegistrationSuccess(FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent $event)
```

But I get:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to BISSAP\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener::onRegistrationSuccess() must be an instance of BISSAP\UserBundle\EventListener\FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent, instance of FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent given
```

And when I replace `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` by `REGISTRATION_CONFIRM`  in RegistrationConfirmListener.php :

```
namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('bissap_bodyconcept_homepage');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

I get no error, but the redirection doesn't work.

Info: I use the original RegistrationController.php from FOSUserBundle

Comment: You missed the first back slash. It's public function onRegistrationSuccess(\FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent $event)

Comment: Yup, you need the initial "\" to take it to the global namespace otherwise it will be looking for the class/namespace in the current one. Alternatively you could add `use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent` and then in your method `public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)`.